# How to get buffers to remain independent when overlapping in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3.

I have several survey sites that I've put a 100m buffer around to see what the habitat composition is for each of those buffered areas.
There are several sites that are close enough together that the buffers overlap like this:

[image]

When I do the intersect between the habitat layer (not pictured) and the buffer zones, it counts each overlapping area as a new section of the site like this:

[image]

So instead of the attribute table looking like:

[image]

It does this:

[image]

What tool/etc can I use that will ignore overlapping and report the information from the intersect of the buffer zone with the habitat layer in a single row for each site?

If each of those habitat types needs to be in a new column - fine by me - I just need everything for each site in a single row.

If I dissolve the buffers, then these three will be one site (no good).

If I use "Remove Overlap (multiple)" and use the Thiessen method (or any of them) it doesn't report on the full 100m extent (also no good).

I've tried searching, but none of my searches have produced an answer that fits what I need.

For @FelixIP, how it handles different types of habitat in one area:
[image]

Comment: If the habitat layer is a vector file you may try a spatial join using join as combination rule on your habitat class field

Comment: How do you treat cases when single buffer intersect more than 1 habitat? You should treat case shown the same way.

Comment: There are multiple columns, with a major cover, a detailed cover, percent cover, and several more. I'll add a screenshot of what the table looks like with a single, non-overlapped, area to my post.

Comment: You might check these links out: https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-documents/spatial-join-s-hidden-trick-on-how-to-transfer/ta-p/1050240  The first option is a spatial join with a merge rule of join and a comma delimiter, which may be what J.R was suggesting